# Isolate interactions across both factors and columns?

Tags: r

I am new here and have been searching for many hours, so I’m sorry if this is answered elsewhere and could be better formulated. I would like to isolate the counts based on the interaction of factors within a column *and* across other columns so I can perform some analysis on the counts. Here is a toy dataset of the counts of parasites in hosts with two taxonomic levels of each. The dataset is much larger in both dimensions.

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 16)), c("count", "hostclass","hostspecies", "parclass","parspecies"))  
df$count <- c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3)  
df$hostclass <- c(rep("mammal",8),rep("bird",8))  
df$parclass <- c("cestode",rep("trematode",5), rep("arachnid",6),rep("cestode",4))  
df$hostspecies <- c(rep("human",3),rep("dog",3),rep("cat",2), rep("crow",4),rep("duck",4))  
df$parspecies <- c("worm1",rep("fluke1",3), rep("fluke2",2), rep("tick1", 3), rep("tick2",3),rep("worm2",4))
```

Here is a bit of the toy data:

> df
>      count hostclass hostspecies  parclass parspecies
>   1      1    mammal       human   cestode      worm1
>   2      2    mammal       human trematode     fluke1
>   3      1    mammal       human trematode     fluke1
>   4      2    mammal         dog trematode     fluke1
>   5      1    mammal         dog trematode     fluke2

I can split the data frame into a list based on the interaction in two columns, and then isolate the counts:

```
Inter <- split(df, with(df, interaction(df$hostclass, df$parspecies)), drop = TRUE)  
cnts <- lapply(Inter,'[[',1)
```

But I would like to do this for each interaction of host and parasite grouping:
1) hostspecies-parspecies;
2) hostspecies-parclass;
3) hostclass-parspecies (example above);
4) hostclass-parclass.

In other words, I would like the interaction of the factors in two columns, and extended to all the interactions of all the host and parasite columns.

Ideally the output would look like cnts, only much longer, since it would include all the interactions listed in 1 to 4 above. 
Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you can use count `(n())` on grouped `(group_by)` columns